# Zero trick in WinBUGS for truncation

Tags: bayesian, bugs

I am using the Zero-trick to create a prior for correlation parameter. Data `y` is a bi-variate normal with covariance matrix with same diagonal elements and correlation phi. The covariance matrix is positive definite for `|phi| < 1`, the usual range for correlation. But instead of common prior `phi ~ uniform(-1,1)`, I am using

```
phi ~ dnorm(0,1)
O <- 0
O ~ dbern(cons)
cons <- step(phi*phi-1)
```

The zero trick should force `|phi| < 1` but the Gibbs sampler picks up illegitimate values for `phi` and the code crashes.
I have a more complicated model than this where I can't use uniform priors.
Here is the code if you want to check yourself.

```
model
{
for (i in 1:n) {
    y[i,1:2] ~ dmnorm(mu[1:2], Sinv[,])
   } 

# Priors
 for (i in 1:2) {mu[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01) }

# Get the precision matrix Sinv from the var-cov matrix
Sinv[1:2,1:2] <- inverse(Sig[1:2,1:2]) 

# Inverse Gamma prior for variance parameter sigma
 tau ~ dgamma(1,1)
 sigma <- 1/tau

# Build the var-cov matrix Sig from variance and correlation (phi)
 Sig[1,1] <- sigma
 Sig[2,2] <- sigma
 Sig[1,2] <- sigma*phi
 Sig[2,1] <- Sig[1,2]

# Constrained priors for phi using the "Zero-trick"
# phi ~ dunif(-1,1) # We could use this but want to see if zero-trick works

phi ~ dnorm(0,1)
O <- 0
O ~ dbern(cons)
cons <- step(phi*phi-1)

}

# Initial values
list(mu = c(0,0),
tau=1,phi=0)

# This dataset causes OpenBUGS code to crash
list(n=5,
y = structure(.Data = c(
5.8, 2.7,
1.3, 5.2,
9.1, 7.9,
8.5, 7.6,
2.7, 5.2),.Dim = c(5,2)))
```

Comment: I don't see where `O` is actually used anywhere to inform your model.

Comment: In the zero-trick O ~ dbern(cons) forces cons=1 (because O is 0 with probability=1) which further forces phi*phi1 < 1.